How to create python wheel for each platform and only include binaries for that specific platform
My project has the structure:
project
- binaries
   - win32
   - win64
   - linux32
   - linux64
   - linuxarm
   - darwin64
   - darwinarm

Each of the folders contains binaries that the project uses that are specific to the platform.
I'm trying to create a wheel for the project. I'm thinking that I should have a wheel for each of the platforms listed and include only the folder for that platform. Ideally, I can rename the folder to something generic so that I can simplify the code that invokes the needed binary.
Would anyone have any thoughts on how I could do this?
Apologies if this question is a bit vague. I'm very new to using wheels.

Where from these binaries come? Did you compile insode the project them using pip wheel or python setup.py or python -m build? Or they're just binaries that come from outside?

No, they're binaries that come from outside.

That would be harder to implement. Python packages build tools pack what they see in the directories, no magical restructure; installation tools install what they have in the archive. So for every platform you need to copy the entire directory, move one necessary binary in place, remove everything else and pack a distribution; remove the temporary copy afterwards.

That's too bad. Thanks for letting me know... saved me many hours of trying to discover a setup that doesn't exist.
